# screen_name changes to id

Tags: solspace-user, solspace

I am using the SolSpace user plugin and ran into a minor issue and hope someone can help.

I have an input field that users can change their screen name but when I go to change my screen name it removes my name and replaces it with an ID and not my new screen name (From Tony to 1) I used the sample code from the SolSpace site but just don't know why the screen name is deleted and replaced with an ID.

I know its a silly thing but just don't know what?! Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
Tony

Comment: Can you post the versions of User and EE that you are using? Can you also post your template code, or at least the link in the documentation from which you used the code? We would need to know you're using {exp:user:edit} or something else.

Comment: Sorry about not adding any details:

I am using User 3.4.4 and the code I used is from the code from this page: http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/edit/#examples

All my other fields update just fine but its the screen name tag that changes the value... Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you perhaps using the **Screen Name Override** feature? If so, your screen_name field might be saved as something else based on the contents of the fields set for the **Screen Name Override**. For example, if your **Screen Name Override** setting is `first_name|last_name`, whatever you set for the screen_name will be replaced by what is in fields `first_name` and `last_name`.

If this isn't the case, try the `{exp:user:edit}` form on a completely, absolutely blank EE template with nothing whatsoever on it besides the code. This is to rule out any effect of javascript/jQuery or other tags (native or third-party) on your form.

Comment: Thank you! It was the Screen Name Override, didn't even notice it till you said, thank you so much for the superb support everything working now. Best regards

Comment: Great! Glad that was it. Don't forget to mark this as the solution if this worked for you :)